# Wix bootstraper does not detect previous version

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, installation

I have problems with WiX bootstrapper after project is rebuilt. When I launch freshly built bundle exe I see a window with Install option instead of "Modify or Uninstall".

What do I have to do in bundle to force it to detect previously installed version?

**EDIT:**
I have found nice article about custom WIX Managed Bootstraper Application. On the basis of steps presented in the article I have created Custom BA app. 
Now, after bootstraper rebuild I am able to show "Uninstall" button (Custom BA detects that product is installed), but launching "Unistall" action does nothing...
Maybe I need to pass any argument to the command? Any ideas?